# Is the anime loyal to the manga aside from switching parts of the story?

Tags: jigokuraku

I was watching *Jigokuraku* (Hell's paradise).  After an episode, I wanted to know how it continued in the manga. I noticed they switched some events in the timeline, an event that happened before in the anime, happened after the episodes I watched in the anime. Are these the only types of changes than the anime does in relation to the manga (changing the order of some events), or do they actually alter the story?